# How to add decimal places to numbers without them and add decimals to those with only one decimal column

Tags: sql, oracle

So i have a column that is number by type, there are values in there with numbers like 8, 15.0, 89.1 or null. I need to add a decimal spot to them so they would look like 8.00, 15.00, 89.10 and the nulls replaced with 0.00.( there are hundreds of number values not just the 4 examples) I figured I needed to do an update with a case, the null part is simple enough

```
update table 

set cost  = case

when  null then 0.00
```

not sure how to tackle the other three situations, any help is much appreciated !!

Comment: If the data type is `number`, the column itself has no concept of the number of decimal places.  The values 89, 89.0, 89.00, and 89.000 are all exactly identical.  When you fetch the data and produce a string that is a human understandable representation of the number, you can choose how many decimal points to use to display the number.  Whether it makes sense to set the `null` values to 0 in an `update` statement or just display a "0.00" string when you query the data is a question you'd need to answer

Comment: @JustinCave ugh no the problem is this is old legacy data that should have been input with those decimal places, now just needs to be corrected. the nulls to 0 is what i need in that particular case but it sounds like based off your answer i may be out of luck

Comment: If the column is a number, there is literally no difference in how the data is stored when a human enters '89', 89.0', '89.00', or '89.0000000000'.  Oracle has no way of knowing what the original human typed in.  All those values are stored identically.  Nothing could have been done in the past with this "legacy data" to cause it to have or to not have a particular number of decimal points.  It is possible that there was some legacy system that stored the data as strings and preserved the formatting that the human typed in.

Comment: well couldnt i using a mapping table create two columns one filled with the numbers one a varchar, set the varchar column equal to the number and then add the trailing decimal places then update the original column using the varchar column, seems convoluted but i dont have any other ideas at this point

Comment: If you are ending up with data stored in a `number` column, there is no way to specify leading or trailing 0's.  The binary representation of 89, 89.0, 089.0000, 00000000089.000, etc. are all exactly identical.  You could certainly add an additional column to the table that stores the number of decimal places to use when rendering the data.  But that would only make sense if you didn't want the display layer to always convert the number to a string with 2 decimal digits

Comment: From your question, you seem to believe that Oracle could store the number 3, in `number` data type, with two decimal places, something like 3.00. Sorry, but no; actually, there is no software on Earth that stores the number 3 as 3.00. Any software that you think does that, actually stores strings, not numbers (no matter what you think, or what the software authors themselves may say).

Answer (score 0):

> So i have a column that is **number** by type

To me, it looks like a *presentation* issue, not *storage*. Justin tried to convince you that you don't have to do anything about it, I suggest you re-read what he said.

Table looks like this:

```
SQL> create table test (col) as
  2    select 8     from dual union all
  3    select 15.0  from dual union all
  4    select 89.1  from dual union all
  5    select null  from dual;          --> only NULL should be replaced by 0

Table created.
    
SQL> update test set col = 0 where col is null;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

If you don't do anything, this is the result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

       COL
----------
         8
        15
      89,1
         0

SQL>
```

As of presentation: it depends on a tool you use. For example: if it were SQL*Plus, you could format the column as

```
SQL> column col format 90D00
SQL> select * from test;

   COL
------
  8,00
 15,00
 89,10
  0,00

SQL>
```

Comma is a decimal character in my database; change it to a dot:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from test;

   COL
------
  8.00
 15.00
 89.10
  0.00

SQL>
```

Or, in any tool, use the `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> select col, to_char(col, '90D00', 'nls_numeric_characters = ''.,''') result from test;

       COL RESULT
---------- ------
         8   8.00
        15  15.00
      89,1  89.10
         0   0.00

SQL>
```

Or, if it is some GUI tool (be it Oracle Forms, Reports, Apex, ...), it contains the **Format mask** property you should use for the same purpose - presentation - and put `90D00` into it to format value displayed to end users.

---

Therefore, once again: there's nothing wrong with values stored in that column; it is just about the way users will see them.